# func tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to call `viewModel.userDidSelectItem(identifier: "DetailMainViewController")` function when the user clicks on a cell but I'm not able, first `print(indexPath.row)` is nil and second I don't know if its correct the call.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!
    var viewModel: MainViewModel = MainViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.loadUsers {
            self.tableview?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.fakeUsers?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fakeUserObjectCell") as! MainTableViewCell
        cell.fakeUserObject = viewModel.fakeUsers?[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       print(indexPath.row)
       viewModel.userDidSelectItem(identifier: "DetailMainViewController")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using the tableview you need to set the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to the `MainViewController`.
And override the below  function

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: You do not need to override `numberOfSections(:)`

Comment: If this was related to the problem then there would have been no cells to try to select.